# Sum form values in responses sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to sum incoming numbers that are user inputted via Google Forms and then transferred to a Google responses spreadsheet.

I have tried the basic functions in my attempts to solve this, but when new information drops into the responses spreadsheet, the formulas all move down a row since the incoming information is inputted at the highest row that hasn't received the Forms output.

If there is a way to sum the incoming data on a Google spreadsheet that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values you wish to sum happen to be in ColumnsD:E of the responses sheet then:

```
 =ArrayFormula(C2:C101+D2:D101+E2:E101)
```

in Row2, after a response has been received, of a spare spare column may suit.